# Harmonic oscillator differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help finding the equations of the solution for which $y(0)=-2$ and $v(0)=0$.

The differential equation was: $2d^2y/dt^2+6dy/dt+9y$

I rewrote the equation as a quadratic and got my general solution to be

$y=c_1e^{-3t}\cos(3/2t)+c_2e^{-3t}\sin(3/2t)$

For condition $y(0)=-3$ I plugged $0$ in for $t$ and got

$-3=c_1e^{-3(0)}\cos(3/2(0))+c_2e^{-3(0)}\sin(3/2(0))$

Then $-3=c_1$

Is this correct so far? How do I go about using the other condition $v(0)=0$?

Comment: Differentiate your solution, plug in zero, set the result equal to zero. Also, please use MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

$v(0)=y'(0)$, so take the derivative of your solution and plug this in.  You will find a value for $c_2$ and have your full solution.

Comment: alright. Would the derivative be: y= 9c1e^3t(cos3/2t)+3e^-3t(sin3/2t)-3c2e^-3t(sin3/2t)+c2e^-3t(cos3/2t)

Comment: It would really help if you would format your material in MathJax.  A tutorial is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  Note that $3/2t$ is ambiguous:  it could be $\frac 32t$ or $\frac 3{2t}$  In this case, it is clearly $\frac 32t$ but you are making it harder on your readers.  When you say e^3t that should be $e^3t$, not $e^{3t}$ which you intend.